# Adding another column to jquery datatables

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have a jquery datatabe that loads data from restful service. I want insert a Edit Button (maybe a .gif image) in the last column, and when the user click in this button, the system should redirect to another page sending the id (its a column from datatable) to another page. It is possible? How could I do that?

Javascript from my datatable:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var table = $('#dtEventList').DataTable( {
    "ajax": "/m1kserv/event/listAll",
    "sAjaxDataProp": "",
    "aoColumns": [
                  {"data": "id"}, 
                  {"data":"name"},
              ]
} );
```

} );

Answer (score 0):

add parameter when you create datetables:

```
"columns": [{
    "data": null,
    "title": "edit",
    "defaultContent": "<button class='edit-btn'>edit</button>"
 }],
 "createdRow": function(row, data, index) {
    var editBtn = $($('td', row).find('.edit-btn'));
    //do somthing
 }
```

you can search the [api](https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/row_callback.html), I'm hoping to help you !

Comment: First, thank you for answer. If I add "data":null to parameter "columns" I get an error. I think it is because the amount of fields in datatable is different from JSON result. Every time that fields amount is different I get this error: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined"

Comment: And the method "createRow" should not be "createCol"?

Comment: I don't know why you use the parameter is not the same as mine and this is my [jsfiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/huangmin/4s7xhdnz/) .